# pivot wider not working with group_by in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

I have the following data set:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
66L, 67L, 68L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 81L, 84L, 85L, 93L, 95L, 
96L, 104L, 107L, 109L, 116L, 126L, 133L, 135L, 138L, 139L, 146L, 
150L, 154L, 164L, 165L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 66L, 
67L, 68L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 81L, 84L, 85L, 93L, 95L, 96L, 
104L, 107L, 109L, 116L, 126L, 133L, 135L, 138L, 139L, 146L, 150L, 
154L, 164L, 165L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 
20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 81L, 84L, 85L, 93L, 95L, 96L, 104L, 
107L, 109L, 116L, 126L, 133L, 135L, 138L, 139L, 146L, 150L, 154L, 
164L, 165L), .Label = c("33714", "35377", "38623", "38806", "39593", 
"39820", "39951", "40286", "40556", "40798", "40800", "40815", 
"43762", "50848", "52183", "52461", "52577", "53202", "53320", 
"53873", "54153", "54206", "54581", "55122", "55267", "55462", 
"55612", "55920", "56022", "56307", "56420", "56679", "57405", 
"57445", "57480", "57725", "57809", "58004", "58215", "58229", 
"58503", "59326", "59327", "59344", "59361", "59865", "60099", 
"60100", "60280", "60384", "60429", "60493", "60503", "60575", 
"60603", "60664", "60846", "61415", "61656", "61749", "61883", 
"62081", "62210", "62285", "62937", "62983", "63327", "63329", 
"64081", "64328", "64418", "64507", "64596", "65178", "65250", 
"65302", "65478", "65480", "65487", "65572", "65802", "65935", 
"65974", "65975", "65978", "65991", "65995", "66013", "66154", 
"66237", "66245", "66389", "66396", "66460", "66572", "66589", 
"67174", "73230", "73525", "73539", "73677", "73942", "73953", 
"74034", "74113", "74114", "74427", "74439", "74607", "74641", 
"74657", "74794", "74800", "74836", "74942", "74952", "74962", 
"74969", "74977", "74985", "74989", "75220", "75229", "75407", 
"75653", "75732", "75735", "75757", "75895", "75898", "76381", 
"76559", "76574", "76594", "76595", "76746", "76751", "76755", 
"76759", "76775", "77088", "77091", "77099", "77134", "77188", 
"77203", "77252", "77304", "77413", "77453", "77528", "77556", 
"77585", "77668", "78262", "79724", "79730", "79850", "79977", 
"80052", "80819", "80901", "80932", "81064", "81065", "81071", 
"81098", "81142", "81175"), class = "factor"), Timepoint_yrs = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Sex = c("Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male"), 
    Timepoint = c("bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
    "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
    "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
    "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
    "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
    "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
    "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
    "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
    "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
    "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
    "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
    "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
    "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
    "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
    "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
    "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
    "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu2", 
    "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
    "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
    "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
    "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
    "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
    "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
    "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
    "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
    "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
    "flu2"), mean_AD = c(0.0010333, 0.00105981, 0.00113736, 0.001108715, 
    0.00104864, 0.00110772, 0.00109096, 0.00109855, 0.00104169, 
    0.00112465, 0.001096525, 0.000985059, 0.001098955, 0.001069465, 
    0.00105376, 0.00106878, 0.00110388, 0.00108702, 0.001162835, 
    0.001070955, 0.0010971, 0.00111695, 0.001060525, 0.00108797, 
    0.00103262, 0.001117605, 0.001061707, 0.001156365, 0.00104431, 
    0.00109114, 0.001053765, 0.001045395, 0.00106441, 0.00108481, 
    0.0011145, 0.001095115, 0.001099075, 0.001057, 0.001096125, 
    0.00109696, 0.001064795, 0.00108024, 0.00102137, 0.001103185, 
    0.00111948, 0.001110965, 0.00103784, 0.00104419, 0.00101302, 
    0.00108785, 0.001098765, 0.001052415, 0.0010976, 0.001064385, 
    0.001129705, 0.001076575, 0.001049785, 0.00103181, 0.001078155, 
    0.001129015, 0.001024814, 0.00109171, 0.001007862, 0.001099885, 
    0.00109162, 0.001060665, 0.00106572, 0.00106803, 0.00113409, 
    0.001052505, 0.001138575, 0.00108723, 0.001046765, 0.001090765, 
    0.001060205, 0.0010143, 0.001106365, 0.00113328, 0.001045545, 
    0.001081185, 0.001102495, 0.00108775, 0.001055425, 0.001130705, 
    0.00115777, 0.00105974, 0.001089395, 0.001069105, 0.001054605, 
    0.00107229, 0.001128765, 0.001111455, 0.001111155, 0.001095955, 
    0.001108905, 0.001077275, 0.00104525, 0.00111458, 0.001110655, 
    0.001114555, 0.00110557, 0.001167755, 0.0010552, 0.00110002, 
    0.00104991, 0.001069695, 0.001101185, 0.001066815, 0.00109388, 
    0.001079455, 0.001097655, 0.001106855, 0.00108804, 0.001102495, 
    0.001077445, 0.00104224, 0.001064015, 0.00110557, 0.00112483, 
    0.001093865, 0.00105965, 0.001048305, 0.0010719, 0.001098505, 
    0.001073105, 0.001049325, 0.001097175, 0.00111584, 0.001122035, 
    0.001036422, 0.001016249, 0.001015195, 0.00110143, 0.001121325, 
    0.001047755, 0.001063235, 0.001079355, 0.001086495, 0.001074005, 
    0.00109106, 0.00103907, 0.0010907, 0.001101685, 0.001017475, 
    0.00113138, 0.001086615, 0.001076375, 0.001088265, 0.00106309, 
    0.00106822, 0.001052205, 0.001106125, 0.001060125, 0.00106945, 
    0.001092695, 0.00107696, 0.001063425, 0.001116725, 0.00105891, 
    0.001054205, 0.00109295, 0.00109387, 0.00101807, 0.001066195, 
    0.001120295, 0.001111565, 0.001088595, 0.00102183, 0.0010934, 
    0.00111935, 0.00105371, 0.00108314, 0.0011006, 0.001079585, 
    0.001127775, 0.001140825, 0.00106203, 0.001118035, 0.00103535, 
    0.00099512, 0.001078955, 0.00108867, 0.0010789, 0.001030445, 
    0.00106243, 0.001028545, 0.00108679, 0.00105624, 0.001110145, 
    0.00107318, 0.00106523, 0.001103515, 0.00112404, 0.001064455, 
    0.001040425, 0.001059305, 0.00106362, 0.001079395, 0.00107183, 
    0.0010652, 0.00106983, 0.00111722, 0.00114111, 0.001059649, 
    0.001029902, 0.001062825, 0.001102155, 0.001122135, 0.00103623, 
    0.00108648, 0.001081035, 0.001110075, 0.001039397, 0.001057715, 
    0.0010338, 0.001071455, 0.001072065, 0.001032233, 0.00111996, 
    0.00106407, 0.0010693, 0.001104395)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -222L), groups = structure(list(
    ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
    32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 47L, 
    48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 60L, 61L, 
    62L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 81L, 84L, 85L, 
    93L, 95L, 96L, 104L, 107L, 109L, 116L, 126L, 133L, 135L, 
    138L, 139L, 146L, 150L, 154L, 164L, 165L), .Label = c("33714", 
    "35377", "38623", "38806", "39593", "39820", "39951", "40286", 
    "40556", "40798", "40800", "40815", "43762", "50848", "52183", 
    "52461", "52577", "53202", "53320", "53873", "54153", "54206", 
    "54581", "55122", "55267", "55462", "55612", "55920", "56022", 
    "56307", "56420", "56679", "57405", "57445", "57480", "57725", 
    "57809", "58004", "58215", "58229", "58503", "59326", "59327", 
    "59344", "59361", "59865", "60099", "60100", "60280", "60384", 
    "60429", "60493", "60503", "60575", "60603", "60664", "60846", 
    "61415", "61656", "61749", "61883", "62081", "62210", "62285", 
    "62937", "62983", "63327", "63329", "64081", "64328", "64418", 
    "64507", "64596", "65178", "65250", "65302", "65478", "65480", 
    "65487", "65572", "65802", "65935", "65974", "65975", "65978", 
    "65991", "65995", "66013", "66154", "66237", "66245", "66389", 
    "66396", "66460", "66572", "66589", "67174", "73230", "73525", 
    "73539", "73677", "73942", "73953", "74034", "74113", "74114", 
    "74427", "74439", "74607", "74641", "74657", "74794", "74800", 
    "74836", "74942", "74952", "74962", "74969", "74977", "74985", 
    "74989", "75220", "75229", "75407", "75653", "75732", "75735", 
    "75757", "75895", "75898", "76381", "76559", "76574", "76594", 
    "76595", "76746", "76751", "76755", "76759", "76775", "77088", 
    "77091", "77099", "77134", "77188", "77203", "77252", "77304", 
    "77413", "77453", "77528", "77556", "77585", "77668", "78262", 
    "79724", "79730", "79850", "79977", "80052", "80819", "80901", 
    "80932", "81064", "81065", "81071", "81098", "81142", "81175"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(c(1L, 75L, 149L
    ), c(2L, 76L, 150L), c(3L, 77L, 151L), c(4L, 78L, 152L), 
        c(5L, 79L, 153L), c(6L, 80L, 154L), c(7L, 81L, 155L), 
        c(8L, 82L, 156L), c(9L, 83L, 157L), c(10L, 84L, 158L), 
        c(11L, 85L, 159L), c(12L, 86L, 160L), c(13L, 87L, 161L
        ), c(14L, 88L, 162L), c(15L, 89L, 163L), c(16L, 90L, 
        164L), c(17L, 91L, 165L), c(18L, 92L, 166L), c(19L, 93L, 
        167L), c(20L, 94L, 168L), c(21L, 95L, 169L), c(22L, 96L, 
        170L), c(23L, 97L, 171L), c(24L, 98L, 172L), c(25L, 99L, 
        173L), c(26L, 100L, 174L), c(27L, 101L, 175L), c(28L, 
        102L, 176L), c(29L, 103L, 177L), c(30L, 104L, 178L), 
        c(31L, 105L, 179L), c(32L, 106L, 180L), c(33L, 107L, 
        181L), c(34L, 108L, 182L), c(35L, 109L, 183L), c(36L, 
        110L, 184L), c(37L, 111L, 185L), c(38L, 112L, 186L), 
        c(39L, 113L, 187L), c(40L, 114L, 188L), c(41L, 115L, 
        189L), c(42L, 116L, 190L), c(43L, 117L, 191L), c(44L, 
        118L, 192L), c(45L, 119L, 193L), c(46L, 120L, 194L), 
        c(47L, 121L, 195L), c(48L, 122L, 196L), c(49L, 123L, 
        197L), c(50L, 124L, 198L), c(51L, 125L, 199L), c(52L, 
        126L, 200L), c(53L, 127L, 201L), c(54L, 128L, 202L), 
        c(55L, 129L, 203L), c(56L, 130L, 204L), c(57L, 131L, 
        205L), c(58L, 132L, 206L), c(59L, 133L, 207L), c(60L, 
        134L, 208L), c(61L, 135L, 209L), c(62L, 136L, 210L), 
        c(63L, 137L, 211L), c(64L, 138L, 212L), c(65L, 139L, 
        213L), c(66L, 140L, 214L), c(67L, 141L, 215L), c(68L, 
        142L, 216L), c(69L, 143L, 217L), c(70L, 144L, 218L), 
        c(71L, 145L, 219L), c(72L, 146L, 220L), c(73L, 147L, 
        221L), c(74L, 148L, 222L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -74L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 222 x 5
# Groups:   ID [74]
   ID    Timepoint_yrs Sex    Timepoint mean_AD
   <fct>         <int> <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>
 1 33714             0 Male   bl        0.00103
 2 35377             0 Female bl        0.00106
 3 40556             0 Male   bl        0.00114
 4 40798             0 Male   bl        0.00111
 5 40800             0 Male   bl        0.00105
 6 40815             0 Male   bl        0.00111
 7 50848             0 Male   bl        0.00109
 8 52183             0 Male   bl        0.00110
 9 52461             0 Male   bl        0.00104
10 53320             0 Male   bl        0.00112
# ... with 212 more rows
```

I want to pivot `mean_AD` wider across `Timepoint`. However, I get this odd result of `NA` values in some columns:

```
DF_wide<- DF %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Timepoint, values_from = mean_AD)

# A tibble: 221 x 6
# Groups:   ID [74]
   ID    Timepoint_yrs Sex         bl  flu1  flu2
   <fct>         <int> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 33714             0 Male   0.00103    NA    NA
 2 35377             0 Female 0.00106    NA    NA
 3 40556             0 Male   0.00114    NA    NA
 4 40798             0 Male   0.00111    NA    NA
 5 40800             0 Male   0.00105    NA    NA
 6 40815             0 Male   0.00111    NA    NA
 7 50848             0 Male   0.00109    NA    NA
 8 52183             0 Male   0.00110    NA    NA
 9 52461             0 Male   0.00104    NA    NA
10 53320             0 Male   0.00112    NA    NA
# ... with 211 more rows
```

The original DF posted above was created with:

```
 DF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Timepoint_yrs = Age - min(Age)) %>% 
  filter(Age < 35) %>% 
  dplyr::select(ID, Timepoint_yrs, Sex, Timepoint, mean_AD)
```

Expected output *missing* the `Timepoint_yrs`: (If I remove the `group_by` and `mutate` code lines, the `pivot_wider` function works properly.)

```
# A tibble: 74 x 5
   ID    Sex         bl    flu1    flu2
   <fct> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 33714 Male   0.00103 0.00106 0.00106
 2 35377 Female 0.00106 0.00101 0.00107
 3 40556 Male   0.00114 0.00111 0.00105
 4 40798 Male   0.00111 0.00113 0.00111
 5 40800 Male   0.00105 0.00105 0.00106
 6 40815 Male   0.00111 0.00108 0.00107
 7 50848 Male   0.00109 0.00110 0.00109
 8 52183 Male   0.00110 0.00109 0.00108
 9 52461 Male   0.00104 0.00106 0.00106
10 53320 Male   0.00112 0.00113 0.00112
# ... with 64 more rows
```

I'm not sure why this is not working?

Comment: @akrun, I updated the expected output in the question.

Comment: Any reason why you can't ungroup it before pivoting?

Answer (score 2):

There was a column that was not needed - `Timepoint_yrs`, `select` out the column and then it should work.  When we use the 'Timepoint_yrs' also in the code, it will look for the match for the value corresponding to that column as well

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-Timepoint_yrs) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Timepoint, values_from = mean_AD)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 74 × 5
   ID    Sex         bl    flu1    flu2
   <fct> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 33714 Male   0.00103 0.00106 0.00106
 2 35377 Female 0.00106 0.00101 0.00107
 3 40556 Male   0.00114 0.00111 0.00105
 4 40798 Male   0.00111 0.00113 0.00111
 5 40800 Male   0.00105 0.00105 0.00106
 6 40815 Male   0.00111 0.00108 0.00107
 7 50848 Male   0.00109 0.00110 0.00109
 8 52183 Male   0.00110 0.00109 0.00108
 9 52461 Male   0.00104 0.00106 0.00106
10 53320 Male   0.00112 0.00113 0.00112
# … with 64 more rows
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am trying to *keep* the `timepoint_yrs` column, plus have the pivot wider act as you posted here.

Comment: @CanyonView your expected didn't show that.  Also, if you have timepoint_yrs, then the combination wouldn't be correct as it will try to match for that case as well

Comment: @CanyonView Please check the values of 'Timepoint_yrs' `DF$Timepoint_yrs
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [67] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[133] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2
[199] 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2` it doesn't have the same corresponding values

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by same, but each value is "years since visit" so they should be different across `ID`

Comment: @CanyonView I meant to say that for `bl`, the Timepoint_yrs is 0, and that is not the case when the value is 'flu1' or 'flu2', that you get NA.

Comment: @CanyonView you can check this `DF %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   #select(-Timepoint_yrs) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Timepoint, values_from = c(mean_AD, Timepoint_yrs))` and then you will understand why it is not working

Comment: Yeah, thats accurate in terms of data. So then `pivot_wider` can't handle that and using `right_join` as posted below is the best option?

Comment: @CanyonView the `pivot_wider` step returns 74 rows, but if you do right_join/left_join, it duplicates the rows and return the original number of rows.  Probably, you may need to rethink the strategry

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(ID, Sex),
    names_from = Timepoint, 
    values_from = mean_AD,
  ) %>% 
  right_join(DF, by="ID") %>% 
  select(ID, Sex=Sex.x, Timepoint_yrs, bl, flu1, flu2)
```

```
ID    Sex    Timepoint_yrs      bl    flu1    flu2
   <fct> <chr>          <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 33714 Male               0 0.00103 0.00106 0.00106
 2 33714 Male               1 0.00103 0.00106 0.00106
 3 33714 Male               3 0.00103 0.00106 0.00106
 4 35377 Female             0 0.00106 0.00101 0.00107
 5 35377 Female             1 0.00106 0.00101 0.00107
 6 35377 Female             3 0.00106 0.00101 0.00107
 7 40556 Male               0 0.00114 0.00111 0.00105
 8 40556 Male               2 0.00114 0.00111 0.00105
 9 40556 Male               3 0.00114 0.00111 0.00105
10 40798 Male               0 0.00111 0.00113 0.00111
# ... with 212 more rows
```

Comment: This works, but is there a reason the `pivot_wider` can't include the `timepoint_yrs`?

Comment: With `id_cols` you define a set of columns that uniquely identifies each observation. The default are all columns except the one for `names_from` and `values_from`. There must be a conflict with `timepoint_yrs` to fulfill this criteria, therefore it is omitted.